# Dynamic SQL Immediate Execute possible with HEX-code using UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2?

Tags: oracle, plsql, hexdump, execute-immediate

I want to read different sql statements from a CLOB field to HEX-code
I then want to cast the HEX-code back within an a sql-script to varchar2 and to execute it.
Generating HEX-code and casting works, but it does not execute. Can anyone please help me if and how Immediate Execute is possible?

Following example

1. My sql statement I want in a CLOB field

```
drop table customers purge;

CREATE TABLE customers
( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  city varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);
```

2. With a procedure I was given from a retired colleague I generated HEXCODE corretly using RAWTOHEX and UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW. The HEXCODE is correct because the "decrypted" code using CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 looks correct. The following code shows the create statement from step 1:

```
SET LINESIZE 10000
SET serveroutput on size 300000 FORMAT WRAPPED

DECLARE
buffer clob;

BEGIN

    buffer := buffer||UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('64726F70207461626C6520637573746F6D6572732070757267653B0A0A435245415445205441424C4520637573746F6D6572730A2820637573746F6D65725F6964206E756D62657228313029204E4F54204E554C4C2C0A2020637573746F6D65725F6E61');
    buffer := buffer||UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('6D6520766172636861723228353029204E4F54204E554C4C2C0A202063697479207661726368617232283530292C0A2020434F4E53545241494E5420637573746F6D6572735F706B205052494D415259204B45592028637573746F6D65725F6964290A29');
    buffer := buffer||UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('3B');

    dbms_output.put_line(buffer);

END;
/
```

3. What I am missing is that the code should not just be displayed, it should be excetuted so I got the messages **Table dropped.** and **Table created.** in this case.

My result:

```
SQL> SET LINESIZE 10000
SQL> SET serveroutput on size 300000 FORMAT WRAPPED
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2  buffer clob;
  3
  4  BEGIN
  5
  6      buffer := buffer||UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('64726F70207461626C6520637573746F6D6572732070757267653B0A0A435245415445205441424C4520637573746F6D6572730A2820637573746F6D65725F6964206E756D62657228313029204E4F54204E554C4C2C0A2020637573746F6D65725F6E61');
  7      buffer := buffer||UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('6D6520766172636861723228353029204E4F54204E554C4C2C0A202063697479207661726368617232283530292C0A2020434F4E53545241494E5420637573746F6D6572735F706B205052494D415259204B45592028637573746F6D65725F6964290A29');
  8      buffer := buffer||UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('3B');
  9
 10      dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
 11
 12  END;
 13  /
drop table customers purge;

CREATE TABLE customers
( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  city varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: You can use execute immediate with a statement you decode; having it initially as hex isn't really relevant. (Why do you do that?) But you have a problem because you don't have *a* statement, you have two, separated/terminated with semicolons. You haven't said, but I guess you're getting "ORA-00911: invalid character" [when you try](https://dbfiddle.uk/rYibygVa)? You're essentially trying to run a script, which is going to be difficult. Parsing into separate statements isn't trivial - you can have string literals that contain semicolons, and PL/SQL uses them differently...

Comment: You will not have "Table dropped" or something, because SQL interface doesn't provide such (human-readable) feedback. Just an error in case of error, an empty result in case of DDL, a result set in case of `select` or a data associated with host variable in case of PL/SQL or DML with `returning`. You should know the statement you are executing and interpret the result accordingly.

Comment: Why do you store the statement as HEX values?

Comment: I have a system table containing meta definitions of materialized views which are resolved by a store procdure. These look like follows and contain Non-ASCCI characters which often cause problems when sharing between different computers and servers due to different settings
`create or replace view template_MV_customer as
(
  select
       '§TAB(TAB_STORE)QUERY§'    ts,
       '§TAB(TAB_CUSTOMER)QUERY§'       tc
  from
    tab_store ts
    inner join tab_customer tc on ts.store_id = tc.customer_id
);`

Comment: So storing complex SQL statements in a CLOB field and generate HEX out of it is a way to share them without damging the scripts due to different type settings on source and target system. `dbms_output.put_line(buffer);` just shows me the finally correctly "decoded" statement but does not execute it. Why does `execute immediate buffer;` not work in my case? Is there a way to run `execute immediate` ?

Comment: Because it is multiple statements in one string - see my first comment.

Comment: THX Alex, since I actually just need one statement, it works with just one `create or replace view...` statement BUT to my surprise there are invisible charcters or bytes I don't know in my generated / now succesfully stored template-view. When running it, I get sql-error `ORA-00907 missing right paranthesis`. When I open the View in a Window and just press execute + retry it again, then it works. Strange thing is I run the whole process on my PC in one PLSQL-Developer session. I checked the charset AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8, using `UTL_RAW.CONVERT` my VARCHAR. I am so close I hope

Comment: Your client application (PL/SQL Developer) would not be running it as a single statement. It is silently parsing the script and running it as multiple statements in the same session, one after another. You are not doing the same when you try to run it using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and are trying to run it as a single statement (which it is not as it is two statements, so it fails).

Answer (score 2):

You have created the script as the hex-encoding of:

```sql
drop table customers purge;

CREATE TABLE customers
( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  city varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);
```

You cannot run that with an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement because it is not a single SQL statement; it is two statements and Oracle forbids running multiple statements as a single command (to help prevent SQL injection attacks).

If you want to have a single statement then you will need to wrap it in an anonymous PL/SQL block and then, since you cannot execute DDL statements in PL/SQL, you would need to wrap the DDL statements their own `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statements so the script would become:

```sql
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table customers purge';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE customers(customer_id number(10) NOT NULL, customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL, city varchar2(50), CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id))';
END;
```

Then it is a single statement and can be run using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```sql
DECLARE
  buffer clob;
BEGIN
  buffer := buffer||UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('424547494E0A20204558454355544520494D4D454449415445202764726F70207461626C6520637573746F6D657273207075726765273B0A20204558454355544520494D4D4544494154452027435245415445205441424C4520637573746F6D65727328637573746F6D65725F6964206E756D62657228313029204E4F54204E554C4C2C202020637573746F6D65725F6E616D6520766172636861723228353029204E4F54204E554C4C2C2063697479207661726368617232283530292C20434F4E53545241494E5420637573746F6D6572735F706B205052494D415259204B45592028637573746F6D65725F69642929273B0A454E443B');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(buffer);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE buffer;
END;
/
```

Which works (provided that you have a table to drop).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GgfRFF_M)

---

Alternatively, you would need to split the script on the SQL statement terminator (assuming that you just have SQL statements and no PL/SQL statements) and use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` on each individual statement.

A simple example (with minimal error handling) is:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_data RAW(32767);
  v_sql  CLOB;
  v_spos  PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  v_epos  PLS_INTEGER;
  v_len   PLS_INTEGER;
  v_stmt  CLOB;
BEGIN
  v_data := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(
    'drop table customers purge;
CREATE TABLE customers(
  customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  city varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
); '
  );
  v_sql := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(v_data);

  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN v_spos > LENGTH(v_sql);
    v_epos := INSTR(v_sql, ';', v_spos, 1);
    
    IF v_epos = v_spos THEN
      v_spos := v_epos + 1;
      CONTINUE;
    END IF;

    IF v_epos < 1 THEN
      v_stmt := SUBSTR(v_sql, v_spos);
    ELSE
      v_stmt := SUBSTR(v_sql, v_spos, v_epos - v_spos);
    END IF;

    IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE(v_stmt, '^\s*$') THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_stmt);
      BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stmt;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('success');
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
      END;
    END IF;

    EXIT WHEN v_epos < 1;
    v_spos := v_epos + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M3laMYXr)